# Programming/Calculating variance covariance matrix for DEoptim() and SCEoptim()

Tags: r, optimization, covariance, variance, minimization

I am looking for an extension to the r-functions `DEoptim()` and `SCEoptim()` from
the packages `DEoptim` and `SCEoptim`, respectively.

The extension could be in an altered package or perhaps a guide how to calculate/program a Variance-Covariance Matrix from parameters results of global optimisers.

On a sidenote: I am a little surprised not to find the "standard" methods of e.g. `optim()` in the earlier mentioned optimisers.

Comment: How do you define this "variance matrix"?
If the function you are maximizing is a log-likelihood,
and if it is differentiable, 
you can estimate the variance of the corresponding estimator 
from the hessian at the optimum 
(check the `numDeriv` package).
But DEoptim is for general, non-differentiable functions.

Comment: I am talking about the variance-covariance of parameters which were fitted by non-linear regression with either `DEoptim()` or `SCEoptim()` for fitting parametric formulas to data.

Comment: If you're doing maximum likelihood estimation the variance-covariance matrix of the parameters is nothing but the negative inverse Hessian and unless you know this Hessian analytically you'll have to approximate it numerically, e.g. using the `numDeriv` package.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the `subplex` package/function. Which gives you the hessian in the output list.